# keep listing's caption together with listing

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I'm using the tips found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books) to show a code listing with a caption. Sometimes the caption is put at the end of the page and the listing on the next page. How can I keep them together?

Comment: declare it as a float, see documentation of listings

Answer (score 1):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides the means to create a caption using the `caption={[<short/LoL caption>]<long caption>}` key-value interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[My listing]My awesome listing}]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
  { do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

For a "captionless" caption, use the `title` key-value. However, these all parse the listing as-is, allowing for page-breaking where needed and causing a possible break in the (top) caption and subsequent listing. Boxing the entire contents avoids this using the `float` key is encouraged, since a captioned item should be allowed to move and can be adequately referenced:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[My listing]My awesome listing},float]
```